# HTTP Post function is successful but nothing is sent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a hard time figuring out why my POST function is getting marked as successful but nothing is getting sent out. I am getting the 'successful' alert that you see coded below, but I don't see anything happening in my Fiddler application, nor is the database I'm trying to add to getting updated. I've tried all sorts of different HTTP POST methods but I can't seem to get any of them to work. This is my first time really working with Angular or JavaScript in general.

```
$scope.item = {
        Name: "Blah",
        Description: "Blah",
        Quantity: 1,
        Expires: null,
        LocationID: null
    };

$scope.saveItem = function () {
        var data = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://msucs491-spring17-assignment2.azurewebsites.net/api/item',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json"
            },
            data: $scope.item
        };

        $http(data)
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            alert('success')
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            alert('error')
        });
    }
```

Here is a JFiddle link if more code/information is needed or if you would like to test with the entire page: https://jsfiddle.net/LaneLutgen/che71og6/1/

Comment: Try this `data: JSON.stringify($scope.item)`

Comment: Tried that before, no luck

Comment: But its working, you database is updating with items

Comment: @Leguest weird...If you look on my link, i am printing the whole database as a JSON object on my HTML but I don't see it updating when I refresh...

Comment: Its maybe sorting problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b9fx.png)Try This `data: $scope.item` might help.

I tested on your link:

Responce I got is: `{"ID":603,"Name":"Just","Description":"Testing","Quantity":123321,"Expires":null,"Created":"2017-04-30T17:02:17.3782786+00:00","Updated":"2017-04-30T17:02:17.3782786+00:00","LocationID":null}`

Comment: I am already using data: $scope.item. What exactly did you change?

Comment: see the attached image, i posted the data  successfully on the POST link, check the payload. Now it seems there might be problem on middleware codes.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct.

Try to use Postman, is a program to test the Request & Response